# Mqtt broker is disconnecting frequently even though it has a unique client id

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, broker

Hi I have a mqtt broker up and running. I am connecting to it from python using paho-mqtt. 
Code

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        print("connected OK Returned code=",rc)
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)

    print("Subscribing to topic","data/#")
    client.subscribe("data/#")


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
   print("Client Got Disconnected")
   if rc != 0:
       print('Unexpected MQTT disconnection. Will auto-reconnect')

   else:
       print('rc value:' + str(rc))

broker_address="ip"
port = 'port'
print("creating new instance")
client = mqtt.Client(clean_session=True) #create new instance
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message #attach function to callback
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect

print("connecting to broker")
client.connect(broker_address, port=port,) #connect to broker
client.loop_forever() #stop the loop
```

I am using the same code in multiple scripts ,connecting to broker and subscribing to a topic. The frequency of disconnection was less when there were 5-6 scripts. I have around 12-13 scripts connecting to the broker and frequency of disconnects has increased significantly. Is there some thing wrong with the connection in the scripts or its about the broker. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: We can't answer this, you are throwing away any useful information from the `on_disconnect` callback and you haven't supplied any information from the broker as to why the connection is being broken.

Answer (score 1):

My guess though is your broker does not like the fact that the Python client defaults to a null clientid. As per the spec it should treat this as an indication it must assign a unique id to your client, but it may be implementing the spec improperly?

Please try passing a randomly generated / unique client id in your connect(), as this will guarantee your clients are all unique, rather than all having the same id which for your broker means it's kicking out any connected client when a new one with the same id tries to connect.

Comment: Hi, thanks!! this can be a reason. Let me see on how does broker assign a unique client id.

Comment: Didn't solve the issue even when tried with unique client id.

Comment: Hello @chink, may I know did you solve the disconnect issue? If yes, may I know how do you solve it? as I also encounter the same issue.